# Gnuplot: single point in 3D with variable's as coordinates

Tags: gnuplot

I plotted some equations in 3D mode with `parametric` and calculated their extremal points.
This way I got `xPos`, `yPos` and `zPos` as coords.

How do I plot this point in addition to my other graphs?
(latest Gnuplot 4.6.5)

I found this [article](http://www.paranoid-media.de/blog/?p=17), but this handles only static typed coords and Gnuplot crashes when using with splot + xyz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest way to place a single point at given coordinates is to place an empty label with a point at that position:

```
set label at xPos, yPos, zPos "" point pt 7
splot ...
```

Comment: With `sprintf( "min(%.1f|%.1f|%.1f)" , xPos , yPos , zPos )` as title ~> awesome